# How to jump to class declaration inside the same file?

Tags: intellij-idea

How to quickly jump to class declaration?

```
import java.sql.*

class MyClass extends MyBaseClass {

  method1() {}

  private method2() {
    !!Cursor is here!!
  }

}
```

For example in this case jump from inside method2 to line with 'class MyClass'

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that in one shortcut, in two it would be <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd>, or Jump to Navigation Bar - which will highlight current class and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.